# Testing that the package.json types property works for the corresponding javascript file

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm

It is possible to put a types property in a `package.json` file:

```
    ...
    "types": "index.d.ts"
    ...
```

As far as I can tell, you can put whatever you like in this file, with no requirement that the types it *says* the module exports are actually exported, or valid, or anything else.

The issue that I'm having comes from me having not updated this `types` file after renaming a file which it exports. Where this module was used subsequently, the imports failed.

What I'd like to be able to do is determine via an automated test whether or not the file referenced by this `types` property is actually valid, as in, does the module export what this types file says it exports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--declaration` this tsc compile option may can help you to automatic generate `d.ts` file according to your typescript source file.

at `build` hooks in your package.json scripts section, execute `tsc --out index.js --declaration src/index.ts`.